# When can a museum be considered an academic institution?

Tags: research-process

I must admit that although I deeply believe museums, no matter how small, play a very important role in almost any sort of research, proving their scientific character can be sometimes quite awkward. Is there any set of fixed criteria that would allow a museum to be considered as an academic institution if met?

Comment: Hi Wydawnictwo Kle! I'm afraid I don't understand your question, as there is no single definition of “academic institution”. Looking at the definitions of *academic* in a dictionary, many of them could apply to some museums as well: “relating to education and scholarship”, for example (*New Oxford American Dictionary*). I'll add that many large museums have both teaching and research activities, and would definitely qualify as academic institutions in my view.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, lack of clear definition of what is an "academic institution" is one of the reasons of my question. Another, a possible situation when museums are explicitly treated as non-academic almost by definition (what definition?) which excludes their personnel  from certain grants, privileges, government funding etc.

Comment: There is no single definition. Grants and other funding sources clearly specify (sometimes in fine print) what institutions are eligible. “Academic institution” is a vague term, and not one used in legal documents. Asking for a precise definition of a vague term is not constructive. If you want to ask *“Can museum employees apply to NSF grants, and under what conditions?”*, that would be a valid question.

Comment: If one takes into consideration that the institutions that are considered "academic" are usually _evaluated_ in terms of a) scientific work produced by their staff and b) postgraduate educational programs (but only if they do have such programs), I would say that "scientific work from staff members" is what would count as a criterion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [OED definition of academic](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/880?redirectedFrom=academic#eid)

> Of, relating to, or characteristic of an educational institution or
>   environment; concerned with the pursuit of research, education, and
>   scholarship; scholarly, educational, intellectual.

has a focus on education. The [wikipedia definition of academic instituion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Academic_institution)

> Academic institution is an educational institution dedicated to
>   education and research, which grants academic degrees.

also has a focus on education and a requirement to grant academic degrees. To me degree granting is critical to being an academic institution. I do not think of any non-degree granting institute as being academic. Places like the German MPIs and US National Laboratories are cutting edge research institutes, but not academic-institutes.

Non-academic research institutions often have a grants office, just like their academic counterparts. Further employees at non-academic institutions that wish to conduct research can often get a research appointment at a local university.

Comment: I strongly disagree with the degree-granting requirement. I know some large institutions, which I consider academic by the definition of that word, which do not grant degrees. Academies of Science, and French and German research institutes, definitely count as "academic institutions" in my head. In short, every one has their own definition, as I said in my comment.

Comment: @F'x I don't consider the MPIs as "educational" which to me is critical to be academic. I added the OED definition if that helps (but it probably doesn't).

Comment: The American Museum of Natural History in NYC grants Ph.D. degrees.

Comment: @DanielE.Shub I work in a research institution, and we train PhD students who work in our research groups though do not award the degree (their university does award the degree). I do not consider us non-academic.

Comment: It seems to me that any definition of "academic" that excludes the IAS is obviously incorrect.

Answer (score 2):

My answer is "localized".

- In France there is a distinction between museum of arts (arts in a broad sense, antiquities being arts for instance) and museum of natural sciences (biology, paleontology, etc.). The latter is considered an academic institution: part of the people working there have the title of associate or full professor, and they can have PhD students.
- In some european countries (France, UK, belgium at least), some museums are part of a university, so I think we can say that they are academic places.

The real question may be then "are you an academic if you work in an academic institution", and I guess the answer is no.

Answer (score 1):

I think a better definition of an academic institution is whether they contribute to peer-reviewed research.

If museum staff often have *academic* input to peer-reviewed research, then perhaps they could be called an academic institution (in a pragmatic, not legal, sense). However if the museum staff merely serve as a repository of knowledge rather than a source of original ideas, then I would hesitate to call the museum an academic institution.